# nodejs api call is not responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I'm a new bee in JS world and trying to learn NodeJs basics, here is what I'm trying to do.

I've a contact in my mongoDb, Write a get Method to fetch that back to caller. Simple right?

Here is my Router method

```js
import {
  getContact
} from '../controllers/crmController'
const routes = (app) => {
  app.route('/contact').get((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`request URL ${req.originalUrl}`)
    console.log(`request method ${req.method}`)
    next()
  }, getContact)
}
export default routes
```

Here is my customer controller code

```js
import {
  getDbContact
} from '../data-access/crmDataAccess'
export const getContact = (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Controller calling db access`)
  var dbContact = getDbContact()
  console.log(`Controller Recieved ${dbContact}`)
  res.json(dbContact)
}
```

Here is my data access via mongoose

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { ContactSchema } from '../models/crmModel'
const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema)
export const getDbContact = () => {
  Contact.find({}, (err, contact) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error ${err}`)
    } else {
      console.log(`Contact Recieved ${contact}`)
      return contact
    }
  })
}
```

from Console log I can see the data is being fetched from the db but it never respond back to the postman call. I guess something I'm doing wrong in calling db access method from controller.. but fishy, not sure what is it.. 
Can someone please help me? thank you

Comment: (1) `getDbContact` doesn't return the contact, (2) `getContact` does not properly handle the promise.

Comment: Thanks, can you just throw the code here that can implement the same? basically I want these three layers returning one after another all the way to router.. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to `await getDbContact()` (because it is asynchronous), otherwise the code execution will go just through and the contact will always be undefined
2. getDbContact has to return a Promise so it can be awaited. Mongoose methods are Promises, you can just return that.
3. The error handling logic should be in the controller, not in the DB accessor.

Controller :

```
export const getContact = async (req, res) => { // add "async" so you can use "await" inside

    console.log(`Controller calling db access`)

    try {

        let dbContact = await getDbContact(); // use "let" or "const"; "var" is old-school all-purpose ES5
        console.log(`Controller Recieved `, dbContact); // dbContact is not a string. Log it this way
        res.json(dbContact);

    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}
```

DB accessor :

```
export const getDbContact = () => Contact.find({})
                 .lean() // returns simple JSON, faster
                 .exec() // non-blocking
```